# New connection in SQL Developer 01017

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**

This status above I see when I'm trying to create new Connection in SQL Developer 11g EE. 
I tried propably all possibilites with lower/uppercases and numbers.

Here is printscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcHyh.jpg

I was searching for that, but coulnd find solution for this kind of problem.
Thank you in advance and sorry if this problem is trivial, but I am beginner in this:(

Comment: Can you post your computers tnsnames.ora for the database that you've installed?

Comment: Have you actually created the `user123` account, and can you test if you can log in to it from another client, like SQL*Plus?

Comment: @AlexPoole ... I have to learn so much:| I haven't got user123 in my database.
I thought that user will auto-create with connection123.
nvm... now I know how it works. Thanks for idea.

Comment: Right... yes, here you are just creating a connection for SQL Developer to connect to an existing account. You'd have to create `user123` from a suitably privileged account. e.g. connected as `system` (since I can see that in your existing connection list!).